# Scrapy exporting data in multiple cell

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scarpy to extract data from line using spider, But having issue that while yielding the result it saving brackets of list in a cell

here is my spider

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class TestCCodeSpider(Spider):
    name = 'test_c_code'

    start_urls = ['http://github.com/gouravthakur39/beginners-C-program-examples/blob/master/AllTempScalesConv.c/']

    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': "test_ c3.csv",
                       'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}

    def parse(self, response):
        
        ids = response.xpath("//table[@class='highlight tab-size js-file-line-container']/tr/td/@data-line-number").extract()
  
        for i in ids:
            yield {
                'extract': response.xpath("string(//td[@id='LC%s'])" % i).extract()
            }
```

and the result is
[image]

I also tried this

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class TestCCodeSpider(Spider):
    name = 'test_c_code'

    start_urls = ['http://github.com/gouravthakur39/beginners-C-program-examples/blob/master/AllTempScalesConv.c/']

    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': "test_ c4.csv",
                       'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}

    def parse(self, response):

        ids = response.xpath("//table[@class='highlight tab-size js-file-line-container']/tr/td/@data-line-number").extract()
        Code = []
        for i in ids:
            result = response.xpath("string(//td[@id='LC%s'])"%i)
             Code.append(result.extract())
         yield {'extract': Code}
```

But it gives these error

[image]

But the required result is

[image]

Comment: In your last example, remove the `yield` statement, and replace `Code.append(result.extract())` with `yield {'extract': result.extract()}`

Comment: @Gallaecio Thanks for your reply, I will do it as u suggested